# Android SDK Manager MacOS Could Not Select Items For Install

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I install the Android SDK into my Mac for development.  I open the Android SDK Manager and want to install several items from the list shown in the program.  When the list of SDK shown and I want to select the items by click the item or the checkbox in front of the item, I cannot select it but no errors show.  So this moment I cannot install anything.

My Mac is in OSX 10.9.3 and Java version is JDK 1.7.0_25.  I try both Eclipse + ADT and Android Studio 0.8.  In fact that I encountered this problem several months ago and several version of ADT.  I'm not sure is it because of the Java version or anything else.  Does anyone have the same problem similar with me?

Thanks,
Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found my problem few weeks ago.  I found that I did not set the JAVA_HOME environment variable in my Mac.  After I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, the problem does not appear again.  You may check if the JAVA_HOME is set or not and try again after changed.

Wilson

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts too, especially as it was working fine until a recent Android tools update. Eventually I stumbled across a solution: double clicking the item selects it. The tick doesn't immediately show up, but the Install button gets enabled and says "Install 1 package", and if you scroll the item out of view and back the tick is there too.